# Trouble using bash command in python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, tcpdump

I'm trying to convert a bash script to python, and some of the commands don't seem to execute in the way I want them to. Basically, the script should install files, run tcpdump and the monkey command and then uninstall the package.

I'm iterating through apk files and installing them with this function which works fine.

```
def installApk(apk):
        os.system("sudo adb install " + apk)
```

But when I try to run the tcpdump function (which should capture
date and save it to a file) and monkey function

```
def runTcpDump(apkPackage):
       os.popen("sudo -i xterm -e tcpdump src 10.0.2.7 -vvv > /home/seed/Documents/Programs "  + apkPackage  + ".pcap")

def runMonkey(apkPackage):
       os.popen("sudo -i xterm -e adb shell monkey -p " + apkPackage + " -vvv 1000")
```

I get these errors:
sh: 1: cannot create /home/seed/Documents/Programs: Is a directory #(resulting from runTcpDump function I believe)

sh: 2: .pcap: not found #(resulting from runTcpDump function)

sh: 2: -vvv: not found #(resulting from runMonkey function)

Comment: In this command `sudo -i xterm -e tcpdump src 10.0.2.7 -vvv > /home/seed/Documents/Programs`, the `sudo` output is dumped into the file, not the `tcpdump` output nor the `xterm` output; and I think that, as xterm is an X-window program, it does not produce any output.

Comment: That is a good thought but this command works fine in the original bash script and saves all the information and stores it to a file

Comment: Remove space at end of Programs in `"sudo -i xterm -e tcpdump src 10.0.2.7 -vvv > /home/seed/Documents/Programs "`

Comment: @Jobin has the winning suggestion I guess, you construct a filename but it contains an unguarded space, which the shell lexer uses to split the command received into tokens, thus at least this explains the first two errors :-) ... on the third one: What could be in apkPackage? empty string? Spaces inside? Hypens?

Comment: Much appreciated! I was able to execute what I intended with this function:


    def runTcpDumpAndMonkey(apkPackage):
     os.system("sudo -i xterm -e tcpdump src 10.0.2.7 -vvv >     /home/seed/Documents/Programs"  + apkPackage  + ".pcap "  + "& sudo     -i xterm -e adb shell monkey -p " + apkPackage + " -v 500")

Answer (score 0):

Like @Jobin suggested, you need to remove the space at the end of "/home/seed/Documents/Programs " since that would result in something like:

```
sudo -i xterm -e tcpdump src 10.0.2.7 -vvv > /home/seed/Documents/Programs apkPackage.pcap
```

which obviously isn't right. You probably want a '/' after "Programs" rather than a space.

As for the `os.popen("sudo -i xterm -e adb shell monkey -p " + apkPackage + " -vvv 1000")` portion, you'd need to look at what value **apkPackage** has to see why it's complaining about the verbose flags.